# Keypress is failing to record all keystrokes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to capture keystrokes from a textarea and have tried using attributes onKeyUp, onKeyPress, onKeyPressCapture, onKeyDown, onKeyDownCapture. All of them seem to miss some key entries:

[image]

When I enter a new key, one of the ones that was not displaying before then shows, in order.

Because of that queued delay, I'm thinking I might need to put a delay on the console log. But that doesn't actually solve the underlying issue. Does anyone know why this behavior is happening?

Here is the parent (App) and child component (TypeArea)

**Parent**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    // sets up this.props to function

    this.state = {
      textbox_in_parent_state: 'string passed from state of Parent(App)',
      someVar: 'parent_constructor_state',
      text_from_textarea: ''
    }

    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this)
    this.text_capture_from_parent = this.text_capture_from_parent.bind(this)
  }

  text_capture_from_parent(eventObject) {
    this.setState({
      text_from_textarea: eventObject.target.value
    })
    console.log(this.state.text_from_textarea)
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">
            <Header />
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <TypeArea textcapture={this.text_capture_from_parent}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <MarkdownPreview />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      {/* <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>*/}
      {/* <h1>App component written in client/components/App.jsx</h1>*/}
      {/* </div>*/}

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**Child**

```
import React from 'react';

class TypeArea extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      textbox_text: 'string from state of child "TypeArea"'
    }
    console.log(this.state.textbox_text)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Typing Area</h1>

        <div className="form-group">

          <textarea className="form-control" id="textbox" rows="25" placeholder="Type Here" onKeyPressCapture={this.props.textcapture}>

          </textarea>

          <button onClick={this.props.passdown}>Click me</button>

        </div>

      </div>);
  }
}

export default TypeArea
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text_capture_from_parent(eventObject) {
  this.setState({
    text_from_textarea: eventObject.target.value
  })
  console.log(this.state.text_from_textarea)
}
```

`this.setState()` is async, and you are calling directly `console.log(..)` after setting the state, at this moment the state maybe didn't successfully changed already. but luckily `this.setState(..)`is providing a callback when it finished setting the new state. so you can call it like this:

```
this.setState({
  text_from_textarea: eventObject.target.value
}), () => {
  console.log(this.state.text_from_textarea);
});
```

and you should see the actual value.